# Querying database through hybrid connection from an azure node js backend

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure

I need to query an on-premises SQL Server Express database from my Azure app service based on Nodejs. I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server) to add a hybrid connection.

I successfully connected and added this connection to my service. I also added the connection string as:

```
Server=LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Database=smartpointmovil_db;User ID=sa;Password=pass1009
```

Then, I wrote an easy api in node JS for my azure mobile app service:

```
"get": function (req, res, next) {
     var sql = require("mssql");

var config = {
    server: 'LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS',
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'pass1009',       
    database: 'smartpointmovil_db',
    port: 1433
};


var conn = new sql.Connection(config);
var req=new sql.Request(conn);

  conn.connect(function(err){
      if(err){
           console.log("Error connectig: "+err);
           return;
      }


      req.query('select * from smartpointmovil.cat_cadenas where id=1',function(err,results){
                    if(err){
                           console.log("Error during query: "+err);
                           return;
                           }
                    else{
                          console.log("Success: "+results[0].cadena);
                          res.json(results[0]);
                         }
                    conn.close();
      });

  });

}
```

Every time I call this API, I get the following error message:

> Error connectig: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to
>   LOCALHOST:undefined in 15000ms

I did not find the way to define in my code the connection string to be used for the query, so I am including the configuration parameters.

Any idea how to write a node js code to query my local database from an Azure hosted service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, these are the changes I did in my code to make it work:

1. Changed from server name from 'LOCALHOST' to my server host name: 'quandojhv' which is the same name used as host name in the hybrid connection.
2. I removed the instance name '\SQLEXPRESS' in the server configuration parameter.

New configuration parameters in my code are:

```
var config = {
server: 'quandojhv',
user: 'sa',
password: 'pass1009',       
database: 'smartpointmovil_db',
 options: {
    encrypt: true 
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **hostname** (Computer Name) of your on-prem server when defining the Hybrid Connection. Then use the same name to reference that machine in your App Service code.

e.g.

```
Server=SQL-SRV-01\SQLEXPRESS,1433; [...]
```

Hybrid Connections work by hooking the `getaddrinfo` system call, and it's probably unable to tell apart your `LOCALHOST` from the actual `LOCALHOST (127.0.0.1)` of the VM that App Service runs on top of.

Test with `sqlcmd.exe` from the [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console):

```
D:\home>sqlcmd -S tcp:SQL-SRV-01,1433 -U {username} -P {password} 
               -Q "SELECT NAME FROM sys.sysdatabases"

NAME
-------------------
master
MobileServiceZZZ_db

(2 rows affected)
```

Comment: I have already tried that. I changed the hostname in the hybrid connection from "LOCALHOST" to "quandojhv" which is the computer name in the local server. The connection string and the connection configuration in the code was changed  by " ...  server= 'quandojhv\\SQLEXPRESS', ... ". I am getting the same error: "Application: Error connectig: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to quandojhv:undefined in 15000ms"

Comment: Test with sqlcmd.exe and nameresolver.exe, both available in the Kudu console.

Comment: Oh and make sure your SQL instance listens on something broader than 127.0.0.1 since HCM will source packets from the private IP address of the NIC (e.g. If your server is 10.1.1.1 then the flow goes like 10.1.1.1:random_port -> 10.1.1.1:1433)

Comment: NAMERESOLVER quandojhv - resolves to: Addresses: 127.0.0.101; SQLCMD fails with the following error: "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible"

Comment: SQL SERVER instance is listening on all IP addresses on port 1433

Comment: It's working now from sqlcmd, I was able to perform any query to my on-premise database nevertheless I am still getting the same error when making the connection through the API nodejs code: Error connectig: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to quandojhv:undefined in 15000ms. Am I missing something in my code?

Comment: Badly formed connection string? Did you try to restart the Web App?

Comment: Thanks for helping! I finally found and solved the issue.